# Oauth vs. Identity Federation: Ensuring Seamless Authentication for Different Apps Without Re-entering Credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml, federated-identity

Currently, I have the following solution: an app that utilizes an Identity Provider (IDP) for OAuth 2.0 authentication (the IDP does not support OpenID). This application receives an authorization code and then exchanges it for access/refresh tokens to consume APIs. There's also a web application that follows the same OAuth authentication flow.

We have a requirement that, when I'm in the app and want to access a link to the web app, it shouldn't be necessary to authenticate again.

Within the OAuth flow, this would work (since OAuth URLs have Single Sign-On between them). However, to avoid needing re authentication, I understand the following conditions must be met:

1. The browser used to authenticate the app must be the same as the one used for the web app, as the OAuth flow's authentication cookie needs to be active.
2. The authentication cookie's TTL must be equal to the tokens' expiration date, as if the cookie expires before the refresh token, re authentication is necessary.
3. The IDP needs to be configured to allow multiple authentication sessions.

Due to business/security decisions, item 3 is not allowed, and item 1 might not always be true since the app uses an web view that is probably different browser than the web app.

Is there any other OAuth-based way to achieve this solution without satisfying items 1 to 3?

I've been researching using identity federation. However, it's not clear to me whether it solves the problem or if we'd run into the same requirements as listed in Items 1 to 3. For instance, if I use Google as an IDP, upon accessing the app, it will redirect to the IDP, and after authentication, the IDP returns a SAML to my app. Clicking to access the web app, if I'm not in the same browser where I initially authenticated, I would need to authenticate again.

Moreover, having a SAML response alone isn't sufficient, as I still need an access token. In this case, my IDP would need to provide a way for me to exchange the SAML response for an access token (this point i'm still checking if its possible).

Thanks in advance